# add a filter to add a class to tag link in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, add-filter

I want to add a filter to revise the link generated by `get_the_tag_list` in WP. It calls up `get_the_term_list`

```
function get_the_term_list( $id, $taxonomy, $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '' ) {
$terms = get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );

if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) )
    return $terms;

if ( empty( $terms ) )
    return false;

$links = array();

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );
    if ( is_wp_error( $link ) ) {
        return $link;
    }
    $links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag">' . $term->name . '</a>';
}
```

I want to add `class="tag"` but i'm not sure how to write a filter for my functions.php file to target only the `$links[]` bit of that function. Could I just exclude the old link set and add in my modified one somehow?

I was thinking to add something like this, but I have it wrong somehow:

```
add_filter('get_the_term_list','replace_content');
function replace_content($links[])
{
    $links[] = str_replace('<a href="', '<a class="tag" href="', $links[]);
    return $links[];
}
```

Comment: Which version of Wordpress do you use? And is it only for the `tags` taxonomy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a couple of mistakes. First add filter on `get_the_term_list` won't work, because it's not a filter. If you look in the code of `get_the_term_list` you'll see a line like this (depending on your WP version)

```
$term_links = apply_filters( "term_links-$taxonomy", $term_links );
```

So you can add a filter on `term_links-$taxonomy` in your case the taxonomy is tag.

The second mistake you made is the `str_replace` in combination with an array. If you want to use an array you don't need to add the [] after the variable. This is only for assigning the part after the `=` to the next item of an array. In this case you do a `str_replace` on the entire array so you should use `$links` instead of `$links[]` both in the assigning and in the `str_replace` otherwise you would add a new array (with the string replacement) after all the links of your current array.

```
add_filter( "term_links-post_tag", 'add_tag_class');

function add_tag_class($links) {
    return str_replace('<a href="', '<a class="tag" href="', $links);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! 
I have this in my version:
`$term_links = apply_filters( "term_links-$taxonomy", $links );` . 
and to answer your other question, yea its only for the tags. I'm using the tags as peoples names so I want to add in a `no-wrap` class to those so that they don't break the names if there are many. Tried your version but I don't seem to notice it catching that $links hook as the class isn't applied

Comment: @antonanton My mistake, it should be term_links-post_tag instead of term_links-tag. See my edit.

Comment: thx @TeeDeJee, works fine. Much simpler than I would have imagined